# JS output not showing in id tag

Tags: javascript, html

The purpose of it is to perform a series of arithmetic to get a certain value when a certain value is entered into the html input box.

The issue that I am having with my program is that it is not showing any output when I press the calculate button in the html section. Could I get some assistance as to what I did wrong?

```js
var salaryArray = [];
var input = document.getElementById('totalHours');
var screen = document.getElementById('results');
var wage = 15;
var hours = parseInt(input.value);

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function() {
  if (hours > 40) {
    var calculate = wage * hours + ((hours - 40) * wage * 1.5);
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

  } else if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 40) {
    var calculate = wage * hours;
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

  } else if (hours < 0) {
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = array;
  }

};
```

```html
<link href="salary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<p> Enter the following information to calculate your pay.</p>

<p> Hours Per Week: </p>
<input type="text" name="hours" id="totalHours" /></p>
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button></p>

<div id="results"></div>
<p id="receipt"></p>
```

Comment: You need to set `hours` inside the function, otherwise you're getting the value when the page was first loaded, not when they click.

Comment: you have two extra `</p>` after `input` and `button`

Comment: @Barmar I added the hours variable into the function. It doesn't seem to have changed anything regarding the output.

Comment: Inside the function, add `console.log(hours)` (while also having the hours variable above it in the function). What does it output in the console?

Comment: @Dementic Oh yes, good catch. That still didn't affect the output though.

Comment: @TheCodesee I tried that earlier, it didn't affect the output either.

Comment: But what does it output in the console?

Comment: What is `screen.innerHTML = array;` supposed to do? Is that supposed to be `salaryArray`?

Comment: You don't set `calculate` when `hours < 0`. Why are you pushing an undefined variable into the array in that case?

Comment: @Barmar It is. I changed the variables a bit to test out different attempts at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `hours` assignment inside the callback function.

```js
var salaryArray = [];
var input = document.getElementById('totalHours');
var screen = document.getElementById('results');
var wage = 15;

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function() {
  var hours = parseInt(input.value);
  if (hours > 40) {
    var calculate = wage * hours + ((hours - 40) * wage * 1.5);
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

  } else if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 40) {
    var calculate = wage * hours;
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

  } else if (hours < 0) {
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = array;
  }

};
```

```html
<link href="salary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<p> Enter the following information to calculate your pay.</p>

<p> Hours Per Week: </p>
<input type="text" name="hours" id="totalHours" /></p>
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button></p>

<div id="results"></div>
<p id="receipt"></p>
```

This works for the cases where `hours >= 0`. I don't understand what you're trying to do in the negative case. You push `calculate` onto the array without setting it to anything, and then you assign an undefined variable `array` to `screen.innerHTML`.

Comment: Hmmm I did the exact same thing on my end and the output didn't show up. I used both safari and Firefox as the target browser. Could it be because I'm using textedit on a MacBook?

Comment: No, textedit should be fine, but there are definitely better alternatives.

Comment: Are you sure you loaded the updated code into the browser? Use the browser's debugger to see what you're actually running.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I misplaced a tiny portion of the code when I was revising it. I have it working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your globals inside the function.  Also, you need to check hours for isNaN

```js
document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function() {

var salaryArray = [];
var input = document.getElementById('totalHours');
var screen = document.getElementById('results');
var wage = 15;
var hours = parseInt(input.value);
if(isNaN(hours))hours=0;

 if (hours > 40) {
    var calculate = wage * hours + ((hours - 40) * wage * 1.5);
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

 } else if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 40) {
    var calculate = wage * hours;
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

 } else if (hours < 0) {
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = salaryArray;
    }

};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p> Enter the following information to calculate your pay.</p>

    <p> Hours Per Week: </p>
    <input type="text" name="hours" id="totalHours"/>
    <button type = "button" id = "calculate">Calculate</button>
    <div id= "results"></div>
    <p id ="receipt"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think `salaryArray` needs to be global.

Comment: works fine inside the function. But array needs to be changed to salaryArray when hours < 0

Comment: If you put it inside the function it gets emptied each time you click, instead of remembering previous calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `hours` inside the function so you can get the typed value, and declare `calculate` at the top so is available to be used in all the if statements, right now the last `if` is using `calculate` out of the scope.

```js
var salaryArray = [];
var input = document.getElementById('totalHours');
var screen = document.getElementById('results');
var wage = 15;

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick = function() {

var hours = parseInt(input.value);
var calculate = 0; // example of initial value
  
  if (hours > 40) {
    calculate = wage * hours + ((hours - 40) * wage * 1.5);
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

  } else if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 40) {
    
    calculate = wage * hours;
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = calculate;

  } else if (hours < 0) {
    
    salaryArray.push(calculate);
    screen.innerHTML = array;
    
  }

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<link href="salary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<p> Enter the following information to calculate your pay.</p>

<p> Hours Per Week: </p>
<input type="text" name="hours" id="totalHours" /></p>
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button></p>

<div id="results"></div>
<p id="receipt"></p>
</body>
</html>
```